# What's the relationship between navigation and TF?

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I bumped into [an error](http://answers.ros.org/question/61120/how-to-let-pr2-do-2d-navigation-without-left-arm/) that I cannot do navigation.

The error happened is probably caused by wrong tf transformation.

I want to know what's the relationship between tf and navigation, is tf important to navigation?
(I've seen [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF), but I don't understand why tf from left arm is important to navigation).

Thanks in advance~

EDIT:(Thanks to Austin)

As a part of the sensor processing for the PR2, the laser scans are filtered to remove any hits on the body of the robot; this is done by comparing laser scan points to the 3D model of the robot in the URDF, and removing any laser hits from the body of the robot. Since the left arm is present in the URDF, the filter tries to remove it from laser scans, but since there is no TF data for the left arm because it is disabled, the filtering step fails and no filtered laser data is published. Since filtered laser data isn't published, move_base doesn't get any sensor data, and refuses to move.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61122/what%27s-the-relationship-between-navigation-and-tf?/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any data being processed by the navigation stack needs to be able to be transformed using tf.  The left arm is rarely in the critical path for that, but it will be a problem for doing things like self filtering data so you don't avoid your own arm.

You need to provide more information about what the errors actually are, but it is probably some of the safety systems on the PR2 which are preventing you from driving not an algorithmic need for all elements of the pr2's tf tree.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0